# Regarding buoyant force acting on a cone in an accelerated container

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

While solving questions related to fluid mechanics, I came across this particular question:

> [image]

The correct options are (A), (B) and (C). I was only able to mark option (A) with certainty.

I have some conceptual doubts here:

1. What exactly is the significance of '${a = g}$'? (I thought of considering pseudo force, and hence, assumed the cone to be slanted due to it. But the question got complicated.) Does it really influence the answers in any way, i.e., will the answers differ if the container wasn't accelerating, or even moving at all?
2. The second option has an obvious typo error (dimensional error), but even if the force in the option was ${'(πr^3ρg)/3'}$, it still doesn't match my answer. I was able to find the relation between the height(${h}$) of the part of the cone in liquid 1 and ${r}$ as ${h^3 = r^3/2}$. So, ${F = (πr^3ρg)/6}$ (I have considered only buoyant force). Is there any other force applied by liquid 1 which I might be missing here?

Could anyone please clarify both of my doubts?

Comment: As to your question, 1.  If the system is accelerating in the horizontal direction, then the sketch is incorrect. The liquid surfaces would be slanted (at 45 degrees). As you suggested, I would ignore that acceleration and go with the sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the indicated acceleration, I agreed with statement, A.  Assuming that the upper liquid could only push down on the upper section, I integrated the pressure times the horizontal component of surface elements to get a total force of  πρg$r^3$/3. (A poorly written question.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; Just have a little doubt here - Even while integrating, upon setting the limits from 0 to h, I am getting (πρgh^3)/3, and as h^3 = r^3/2, so I am still getting the answer as (πr^3ρg)/6;  [I wrote integral of (dx.ρg).πx^2 and integrated it for x from 0 to h] - Could you please check if I am going wrong somewhere or, if I am missing a concept or so

Comment: You need to integrate the pressure acting down on rings of area at increasing depth.  Note that at 45 degrees, the horizontal component of each incremental area is the same as dx.  dF =  ρgx(2πx)dx.  Also note that the upper liquid does not have access to the bottom of the upper section of the cone. Any upward force comes from the lower section of the cone.

Comment: Oh alright, thank you, now I get it